# Clipping raster by mask in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clip, gdalwarp

When I try to clip a raster layer with a polygon vector layer. QGIS throws and error:

> ERROR 1: The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation
>   between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed
>   for C:\Users\bhoke\Desktop\gisFiles\uydu1.tif. There is no affine
>   transformation and no GCPs. Specify transformation option
>   SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check.

I am new to GIS and I don't know what it means. CRS of both vector and raster layers are same. I tried -to src_method=no_geotransform but it results with a blank image also warns about SRS of vector layer.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: it seems like gdalwarp still tries to transform your raster file's CRS. are you sure both layers are in the same CRS? did you set the layers CRS yourself?

Comment: Yes they are both wgs84

Comment: another reason might be that the extend of your raster data is not set properly. did you georeferrence the raster yourself? or did you download it from somewhere?

Comment: No I did not georeference it. Should I?

Comment: maybe...it is important to know how or where you obtained that data: did you download data from somewhere, was it provided or did you produce the image yourself, and if so, how? or: how do you know that the raster is in WGS84? the point is, a CRS cannot simply be set, it has to be applied to the data correctly. a raster image has to be georeferenced at some point, usually by the data provider. but if you created that image yourself and withouth a spatial reference, than you have to do that yourself.

Comment: additionally, deactivate the on-the-fly-transformation (click on the epsg code at the bottom right of qgis main window and deactivate the checkbox at the top). are both layers where they should be?

Comment: The data is provided by the organization and it is single band Pleiades image. I checked CRS from the properties of the layer, also it does not ask for projection when opening raster file and set CRS to WGS84 automatically(otherwise, it asks for CRS). On the fly projection is disabled by default.

Comment: okay, one more: try raster -> conversion -> translate, set the target crs to epsg 4326 and add '-co worldfile=yes' to the command after 'gdal_translate'. this should create a new raster with a world file that gdal uses for geolocating the source file for gdalwarp. try to clip the new raster again.

Comment: @ThingumaBob It gives another error. But I solved my problem, I was processing another file not the provided one and I think I made some edits to this file unconsciously. When I use original file, it clipped without any problem. Thank you for your help :).

Comment: hehe...tricky little data quirks. good timing though, I was out of ideas anyways ,)